# Profiler for Visual C++ 2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2005, profiling

Any recommendations for gratis (i.e. free as in free beer) profilers which can be integrated with Visual C++ 2005? I'm using [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) right now (which is really nice), but wouldn't mind shifting if there were a better option.

Comment: Hm, if not - why not take the Very Sleepy source and wrap it into an AddIn? The source does look reusable and managed AddIns in e.g. C# aren't that hard to write.

Comment: @gf: Lol, you should probably put that into an answer since there doesn't seem to be another other takers.

Answer (score 1):

AMD CodeAnalyst is the best I've tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being a little unconventional, [this costs nothing and works just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you gotta work on your word choice. I missed the "gratis" there. Leaving my answer just because it is an *amazing* profiler.

If you want a serious solution, get Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite. Also note that the profiler has improved significantly with each new release (2008, 2010), but even in VS2005 it made others seem like half-hearted attempts. In my experience, it is *the* answer for profiling on the Windows platform.

Comment: In 2005, there are some small glitches with the profiler, and the documentation is bad, but the results are impressive; I've used it with great success.